# prevent Q2A redirecting addon domains?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the Q2A script installed http://www.question2answer.org/

I have non-www. & non-https redirecting to www & https perfectly but, somewhere within the htaccess code it's redirecting my add-on domain http://addon-domain.com to https://www.main-domain.com/addon-domain.com/

I suspect it's something to do with the following but, have no idea how to edit it correctly:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Here's the whole code:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
# redirect any domain other than www.main-domain.com to www.main-domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.main-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.main-domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# force https on www.main-domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.main-domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: I need it to redirect to `http://www.addon-domain.com`

Comment: That is already happening in your rules. Does `/addon-domain.com/` have .htaccess also? Test in a new browser to avoid old cache.

Comment: no I haven't any htaccess file for the addon-domain and have tested in another browser same problem

Comment: thanks for your help, you steered me in the right direction I added a htaccess to addon-domain and it how works.